# Changing the number of search results per page with the core search module

Tags: search

What is the best way to change the number of search results per page when using the core search module?

I have both Drupal 6 and 7 sites that I would like to do this with.

In Drupal 6, the value 10 is hardcoded in  [`do_search()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/do_search/6).

In Drupal 7, the value 10 is hardcoded in the hooks, eg [`node_search_execute()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_search_execute/7), and there isn't a tag added that can uniquely identify the query for altering.  The idea has been [floated in the issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/702940), but as of 2013-01-30, nothing has been committed yet.

In the past I have [hacked core](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core) and handled upgrades with patch management using the normal methods.

Comment: ugly as it sounds, what I did in D6 was to create mymodule_search() as a direct copy of node's hook_search() and then made mymodule_do_search() a similar copy but with the number of search results set to mymodule's liking, and then menu altered and so forth a bunch of stuff to gently coerce the users to /search/mymodule/... instead of /search/node/...  and yes, all instead of one tiny core hack :(

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the hook implemented from the Node module is not possible because [hook_search_execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_execute/7) is invoked by [search_data()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/search_data/7) using the following code.

```
  if (module_hook($module, 'search_execute')) {
    $results = module_invoke($module, 'search_execute', $keys, $conditions);
    if (module_hook($module, 'search_page')) {
      return module_invoke($module, 'search_page', $results);
    }
    else {
      return array(
        '#theme' => 'search_results', 
        '#results' => $results, 
        '#module' => $module,
      );
    }
  }
```

`$module` is the parameter passed to `search_data()`. `hook_search_execute()` is similarly to [hook_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7) which is invoked for the module implementing the content type, not for every module.

I was looking for a way to alter the query executed to search nodes, and the only way I found is to alter the page callback for search/node. That is the way that requires less code.  Otherwise, the only alternative I can think of is implementing a search module to replace the search tab implemented for the Node module.

Since Drupal uses [hook_search_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_info/7), but doesn't uses `hook_search_info_alter()`, and `hook_search_info()` doesn't return much useful data (at least to help overriding the search query), I think there aren't other alternatives.

Comment: Ah yes thanks, I saw it was a hook and thought `module_implements_alter` but I see the search module explicitly calls `node_search_execute` as the search providing module there.

Answer (score 0):

A new feature in Drupal 7 is [hook_module_implements_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7)

You could use that to fork/override the [node_search_execute](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_search_execute/7) (hook_search_execute) function in your own module.

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter
 */
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'search_execute') {
    // Sorry node module, no hook_search_execute for you
    unset($implementations['node']);
  }
}
```

and then implement your own copy

```
/**
 * Implements hook_search_execute
 * Override core node_search_execute here with custom implementation
 * Basically a clone of node_search_execute, but with limit variable available
 * See mymodule_module_implements_alter
 */
function mymodule_search_execute($keys = NULL, $conditions = NULL) {
  // Add new limit conf variable
  $limit = variable_get('search_result_limit', 10);
  // Build matching conditions
  $query = db_select('search_index', 'i', array('target' => 'slave'))->extend('SearchQuery')->extend('PagerDefault');
  $query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = i.sid');
  $query
    ->condition('n.status', 1)
    ->addTag('node_access')
    ->searchExpression($keys, 'node');

  // Insert special keywords.
  $query->setOption('type', 'n.type');
  $query->setOption('language', 'n.language');
  if ($query->setOption('term', 'ti.tid')) {
    $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'n.nid = ti.nid');
  }
  // Only continue if the first pass query matches.
  if (!$query->executeFirstPass()) {
    return array();
  }

  // Add the ranking expressions.
  _node_rankings($query);

  // Load results, use limit variable
  $find = $query
    ->limit($limit)
    ->execute();
  $results = array();
  foreach ($find as $item) {
    // Render the node.
    $node = node_load($item->sid);
    $build = node_view($node, 'search_result');
    unset($build['#theme']);
    $node->rendered = drupal_render($build);

    // Fetch comments for snippet.
    $node->rendered .= ' ' . module_invoke('comment', 'node_update_index', $node);

    $extra = module_invoke_all('node_search_result', $node);

    $uri = entity_uri('node', $node);
    $results[] = array(
      'link' => url($uri['path'], array_merge($uri['options'], array('absolute' => TRUE))), 
      'type' => check_plain(node_type_get_name($node)), 
      'title' => $node->title, 
      'user' => theme('username', array('account' => $node)), 
      'date' => $node->changed, 
      'node' => $node, 
      'extra' => $extra, 
      'score' => $item->calculated_score, 
      'snippet' => search_excerpt($keys, $node->rendered), 
      'language' => entity_language('node', $node),
    );
  }
  return $results;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this hook for the same module that implements hook_search_info ? For D6 hook_search, it's clear with the $op.

Answer (score 0):

To get more than 10 search results on one page in Drupal 7, I have used [search_config](https://drupal.org/project/search_config) module. I used it's latest version '7.x-1.1-beta2'.

Once the module is enabled, you can configure the pager limit from Configuration->Search and metadata->Search settings (admin/config/search/settings) under 'ADDITIONAL NODE SEARCH CONFIGURATION' section. You will see 'Results' section there and you can specify pager limit to show more than 10 search results on one page.