# Custom pagination in search results

Tags: 7, search, paging, views

I would like to know how to display a custom pagination in search results. By default drupal search is displaying 10 results but no pagination even `$pager;` is printed in `search-results.tpl.php`. I know this question is asked many times but I did not find the answer. Is there any hook implementation for custom pagination?

Comment: What you want to customize is the number of results per page? Assuming you're talking about searches over node content, the limit of 10 is hardcoded in the node module. For workaround ideas see here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59082/changing-the-number-of-search-results-per-page-with-the-core-search-module

Comment: Yes @dblue, I was talking about pagination, I have also installed `search_config` module but it did not work for me.